# Need to update attributes in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I am trying to use the migration below to add a record then update 4 other records with the new records id. The new record is added fine but the updates are not happening.

```
  def change

    ItemsCategory.reset_column_information

    hub = ItemsCategory.create name: 'HUB RECORD'

    ItemsCategory.where(id: 1..4).each do |p|
      p.update_attribute :parent_id, hub.id
      p.save
    end

    ItemsCategory.build_ancestry_from_parent_ids!
  end
```

Comment: Maybe your condition `where(id: 1..4)` does not return any object from the DB? Try `ItemsCategory.order(:id).limit(4).update_all(parent_id: hub.id)`

Comment: I'll try that but I put a puts in there to confirm it was hitting those records

Comment: that did it! Make it an answer and I'll mark it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not do content changes in migrations.  Migrations are specifically for changing your schema.  Content migrations are an anti-pattern.  You should be handling the content with a custom rake task.

Answer (score 0):

Sean is 100% correct.  You should not use migrations to modify table content but only the schema.  use a custom rake task to do this.  Let me give you an example.

Loading a color table using command "rake db:color" would be:

Put this code in lib/tasks/color.rake:

```
namespace "db" do
  desc "Load Color  database"
  task color: :environment do |t|
    APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../../db', __FILE__)
    puts "Running #{APP_PATH}/color.rb"
    require "#{APP_PATH}/color"
  end
end
```

Put this code in db/color.rb:

```
# Run from lib/tasks/color.rake using:
# rake db:color
# or with tools/rake
Color.delete_all
colors = ["Black", "White", "Silver", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Other"]
colors.each do |c|
 Color.create color: c
end
```